# How do I form these quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A car travels a distance of $1200 \ km$ at a speed of $a \frac{km}{h}$, while a train travels the same distance at $(a – 20) \frac{km}{h}$. If the time taken by the train is $5$ hours more than the time taken by the car, then what is $a$?

How do you form equations to solve this?

Comment: $$v=\frac{d}{t}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is given to you that a car is travelling a total **distance** of 1200 km with **speed** of a $km/h$.

And

A train travels the **same** distance at **speed** of $(a-20) km/h$.

Let us take the time taken by **car** to travel the distance of 1200 km at speed of a km/h be: $t$ hours.
And the time taken by **train** to travel the distance of 1200 km (same) at speed of (a-20) km/h be: $t'$ hours.

Given to you that the time taken by train $(t')$ is 5 hours more than the time taken by the car $(t)$.

So, you can write this as: $${t' = t + 5 }$$

Now, you know that: $$\textbf{Speed} (v) = \cfrac{\text{Distance} (d)}{\text{Time} (t)} $$

Which can be further written as: $$\textbf{Time}(t) = \cfrac{\text{Distance}(d)}{\text{Speed}(v)}$$

So, for **car**, you have: $$t = \cfrac{1200 km}{a \ km/h} $$

And for **train**, you have: $$t' = \cfrac{1200 km}{(a-20) \ km/h} $$

Put these two equations for $t$ and $t'$ in: $t' = t + 5$. Will you be able to go on from here?

Comment: thanks :) that was a really clear explanation

Comment: Good to know that it helped. Best of Luck! :)